# This while loop seems to stay active although i'm entering a valid input (LPL, BOH). I can't seem to find the problem

Tags: python

```
UkAirport = input('Please enter the three-letter code for the UK airport\n')
while UkAirport != 'LPL' or UkAirport != 'BOH':
    UkAirport = input('Please enter a valid three-letter code for the UK airport\n')
```

just code for a school project, was wondering if anyone could help me find the problem here.

Comment: Replace the `or` with `and`

Answer (score 1):

As Martin correctly pointed out, you should replace the `or` with an `and`, as you want the loop to continue **while** the value is different from `LPL` **and** `BOH`.
In addition, this is a classic use-case for a `do ... while` loop, hence I will suggest you to rewrite your code to [not repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
while True:
    uk_airport = input('Please enter the three-letter code for the UK airport\n')
    if uk_airport in ['LPL', 'BOH']:
        break
```

See [PEP 315](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

```
while UkAirport != 'LPL' or UkAirport != 'BOH':
```

Exemple: you type "LPL", the first condition will be **False** but the second will be **True**

> False **or** True  =  **True**

but in you case you want it to be **False**, to fix it you can replace `or` by `and`

> False **and** True = **False**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO and thank you for contributing. I like that you try to explain the boolean logic. Could you please elaborate so that it is clear where the problem is? Perhaps a table would be useful. Answers should be clear and detailed as possible so that the Creator can understand what the problem is.